# How can I find the perpendicular distance between two parallel line segments?

Tags: c++, parallel-processing, geometry, lines, euclidean-distance

I have many parallel line segments, for example L1(P1, P2) and L2(P3, P4).
The Points have each x and y coordinates.
These parallel line segments have varying angles between 0-180 degrees.

How can I efficiantly find the perpendicular space between those line segments in c++? 
[image: Distance between two parallel line segments]

Comment: What did you try so far?

Comment: Are you having trouble deriving the [formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distance_between_two_straight_lines)? Or expressing that formula in C++?

Comment: I have trouble expressing the formula in C++, maybe I just need some simple example to start from there

Comment: this has helped me: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KUXbhlAGeok

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The distance between two parallel lines will be the distance between the first (infinite) line and any point (say, P3) on the second line.  Since you are working with coordinates, it's more convenient to use the vector representation of the formula than to try to express the line as an equation.  Using that representation, in 2d this distance is given by `|(P3 - P1) dot ( norm ( P2 - P1 ))|`, where `norm` is a normalized perpendicular to `P2 - P1`:

[image]

Also note, in 2d, a perpendicular to a vector `(x, y)` is easily given by `(-y, x)`.  Thus:

```
class GeometryUtilities
{
public:
    GeometryUtilities();
    ~GeometryUtilities();

    static double LinePointDistance2D(double lineP1X, double lineP1Y, double lineP2X, double lineP2Y, double pointX, double pointY);

    static void Perpendicular2D(double x, double y, double &outX, double &outY);

    static double Length2D(double x, double y);
};

double GeometryUtilities::LinePointDistance2D(double lineP1X, double lineP1Y, double lineP2X, double lineP2Y, double pointX, double pointY)
{
    double vecx = lineP2X - lineP1X;
    double vecy = lineP2Y - lineP1Y;
    double lineLen = Length2D(vecx, vecy);
    if (lineLen == 0.0) // Replace with appropriate epsilon
    {
        return Length2D(pointX - lineP1X, pointY - lineP1Y);
    }

    double normx, normy;
    Perpendicular2D(vecx/lineLen, vecy / lineLen, normx, normy);
    double dot = ((pointX - lineP1X) * normx + (pointY - lineP1Y) * normy); // Compute dot product (P3 - P1) dot( norm ( P2 - P1 ))
    return abs(dot);
}

void GeometryUtilities::Perpendicular2D(double x, double y, double &outX, double &outY)
{
    outX = -y;
    outY = x;
}

double GeometryUtilities::Length2D(double x, double y)
{
    return sqrt(x*x + y*y);
}
```

In production you will probably want to introduce some sort of `Point` class which would beautify this API considerably, however since it isn't shown I wrote the code purely using doubles.

Comment: Thankk you. Haven't thought about using vectors but it was much easier to understand for me. +1 for the example code!

Answer (score 1):

A quick google search yields this wikipedia article. 
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distance_from_a_point_to_a_line

To compute the distance you need that one line's equation is expressed as `ax + by + c = 0`. You can then use a point of the other line to compute the distance using the formula given in the wikipedia article.

To obtain a line equation in the form `ax + by + c = 0` from two points on the line, use the method described in this web page https://bobobobo.wordpress.com/2008/01/07/solving-linear-equations-ax-by-c-0/
You then obtain the values a, b and c for the line.

Once you have the formula, it is straight forward to convert it to c++.

I would discourage using a line equation in the form `mx + b = y` because you might find yourself with a case where m is infinite. It will then be very difficult to compute the distance. You don't have this problem when using the equation `ax + by + c = 0`.